# How to crop text when overflowing?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, overflow, flutter-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that shows some data, I would like it to fit when overflowing, but the Overflow method does not work for some reason. When using it, I still get an overflow, could you tell me how to fix it?

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Center(child: Text("Statistics")),
    content:  Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
          Text('Total:'),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
            child: Text('232323000000009090900000',   overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),
          ),
        ],),
        SizedBox(height:10),
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
           Text('Best:'),
           Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
            child: Text('27 '),
            ),
          ],),
           SizedBox(height:10),
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
           Text('Lives:'),
           Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
            child: Text('13'),
            ),
          ],),
           SizedBox(height:10),
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
           Text('Removed:'),
           Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
            child: Text('34'),
            ),
          ],),
      ],
    ),
  
    actions: [
      closeButton,
    ],
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap with Text with `Expanded` or `Flexible` and to have space you can use `SizedBox`.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text('Total:'),
    SizedBox( //left space
      width: 10,
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        '23232300000000ssssssssssssssssssss90909sdsad00000zzzz',
        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 9, ), //right space
  ],
),
```

Or `Flexible<Padding<Text>>`

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text('Total:'),
    Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          '23232300 00zsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssadsszzzxsd',
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```